# How to fix main.swift in Mac Project?

Tags: swift, macos, macos-sierra

I wanted to update an old Mac project in Swift, and after all the conversion to Swift 3, I was faced with this error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'C_ARGV'
Use of unresolved identifier 'C_ARGC'
```

And the issue is with this file: main.swift, which consists of only 2 statements:

```
import Cocoa
NSApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV)
```

How can I fixed this to make my project work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@NSApplicationMain` on the top of the `AppDelegate` class (above the `class...` line) and delete `main.swift`.